# Need Tensorflow Suggestions

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a dataset of **ASL**(American Sign Language) in which 3000 images per letter and i am going to train my model by the help of `tensorflow codelabs` using this script

```
 "python -m scripts.retrain \ 
         --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
         --how_many_training_steps=? \ 
         --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \ --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"mobilenet_1.0_224" \ 
         --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \ 
         --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \ 
         --architecture="mobilenet_1.0_224" \ --image_dir=tf_files/dataset".
```

Can any one tell me how many steps i have to choosen for the accurate predictions?

I am new in deep learning suggestions would be helpful as i am in learning phase.

Answer (score 1):

If you have about 3,000 images per letter, and 26 letters, that gives you about 78,000 images per *epoch*. If your batch size is ***b*** then that gives you 78,000/***b*** training steps per epoch. I'd suggest training to 10 epoch first, and see what happens.

This is experimental science. Print the accuracy after each epoch, and see what happens, if the network improves any more. Stop training when it stops improving significantly.